# How to express count(distinct) with subquery in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, distinct

A query results a certain number. The query is:

```
select
count(distinct case when (A or B or C) and D then table_a.field1 else null end)
from table_a
    left join table_b on table_b.x = table_a.y
group by table_a.y
;
```

where A, B, C and D are given conditions. Now, written in this form:

```
select
sum((select count(1) from table_b where table_b.x = table_a.y and ((A or B or C) and D) ))
from table_a
    left join table_b on table_b.x = table_a.y
group by table_a.y
;
```

the result does not match the one we got with count(distinct).

What is the correct way of writing count(distinct) with a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear why you need a subquery. You still have the JOIN, so that subquery is potentially going to be "counting" the same rows multiple times.

If you want to get the number of distinct values for `field1` in `table_a` which meets a set of criteria (on table_a), then you don't really need a subquery on table_b to get that. At least, I don't see anyway that you can get that result using a subquery on table_b.

Here's an example that returns an equivalent result:

```
 select (select sum(1) as mycount
           from ( select a.field1 
                    from table_a a
                    left join table_b on table_b.x = a.y
                   where a.y = t.y
                     and ( (A or B or C) and D )
                     and a.field1 IS NOT NULL
                   group by a.field1
                ) s
        ) as mycount
   from table_a t
  group by t.y
```

That's really the only way I know to get something equivalent to a `COUNT(DISTINCT expr)`. You've got to do a `SELECT expr FROM ... WHERE expr IS NOT NULL GROUP BY expr`, and then count the rows it returns.  In this case, you could use either a COUNT(1) or a SUM(1).

(I'm not at all sure that answers the question you were asking, but it's my best shot at it.)

(We note that in your original query, you have a `GROUP BY table_a.y`, so that query can return multiple rows, each with its own count.