# MySQL Distinct Query with Subqueries optimization

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to take "Galt Barber on August 26 2006" advice here on distinct optimization:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

My query looks like:

```
 SELECT COUNT( `pUserDirectLabor`.`pDate` ) as `daysWorked` 
 FROM   ( SELECT  DISTINCT `user_direct_labor`.`date`  as `pDate`  
       FROM user_direct_labor 
       GROUP BY user_direct_labor.`date`)  
 AS pUserDirectLabor,  user_direct_labor
```

There is only 1 table being queried here.  The table is `user_direct_labor` with the column `date` which is the datetime type.  The table has 12 rows in it.  There are 6 unique dates in the 2013-06-28 00:00:00 format.

If I run just the sub query by itself, I return 6 rows from the database all with unique dates as expected.

When I add in the count(), the result becomes 54.  I'm not sure where 54 is coming from.  I'm fairly novice to sub queries.

If I change it to COUNT( 1 ), it still returns 54.  I'm not sure why to use COUNT(1), but it's what this guy was talking about. 
[How to express count(distinct) with subquery in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439440/how-to-express-countdistinct-with-subquery-in-mysql)

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Figured it out.  The , table after the subquery is the problem.  Not sure why, but removing that fixed it.

Comment: The `, table` was causing a cross-product with the table (it's equivalent to a join with a condition that's true for all pairs of rows).

Comment: I'm not sure why you got 54. If the table has 12 rows, it should have been 6*12 = 72.

Comment: You were right. 9 rows.  It had 12 ids, so I looked at the last id and not actual row counts.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it simple  like this :

```
   SELECT  `date`  as `pDate`  , COUNT(*) as `daysWorked`
   FROM user_direct_labor 
   GROUP BY `date`
```